# Are these Haskell sub-classes redundant?

Tags: haskell

The code in **Listing 1** represents my attempt to implement the following requirement:

*It can be shown that a passenger **on** a boat **in** a boathouse can be said to be indirectly **in** the boathouse.*

The rather unusual formalisation of the requirement is based on code used in a [previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/haskell-type-classes-as-ontological-categories/134863#134863). I am not seeking a drastic alternative coding nor to included Haskell extensions. For research purposes, I need to stay as close to the [original coding](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92366/haskell-type-classes-as-ontological-categories/134863#134863) as possible.

It seems to me that the sub-classes are redundant because functions can only be defined in instances of the class where they were originally declared, not in any sub-class of that original class. Is this correct?

**Listing 1**

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-#  OPTIONS_GHC  -Wno-missing-methods #-}
-- The suffix D=data type,Dc=constructor
-- The data types were chosen to match the type variables in the type classes
data PeopleD = PeopleDc [Char] deriving (Show,Eq)
data BoatD a  = BoatDc a deriving (Show,Eq)
data HouseBoatD a  = HouseBoatDc a  deriving (Show,Eq)
data BoatHouseD a  = BoatHouseDc a deriving (Show,Eq)
                
                 
class ContainersC a b where -- suffix C= class
 insert :: b -> a b -> a b
 remove :: b -> a b -> a b
 whatsIn :: (a b) -> [b]
                
 class SurfacesC a b where  
  put ::  b -> a b -> a b
  takeOff :: b -> a b -> a b
  whatsOn :: (a b) -> [b] 
                               
                
 class PeopleC p
 -- subclasses
 class ContainersC h o => HousesC h o
 class (SurfacesC v o) => BoatsC v o
 class (HousesC h (v p), BoatsC v p) => BoatHousesC h v p
 class (BoatsC v p, HousesC v p, PeopleC p) => HouseBoatsC v p 
                             
               
 instance ContainersC BoatD PeopleD where
   whatsIn (BoatDc (PeopleDc x)) = [PeopleDc x]
                
 instance ContainersC BoatHouseD (BoatD PeopleD) where
  whatsIn (BoatHouseDc (BoatDc (PeopleDc x))) = [(BoatDc(PeopleDc x))]
              
 instance SurfacesC BoatD PeopleD where
  whatsOn (BoatDc (PeopleDc x)) = [PeopleDc x]
         
 test =  (head (whatsOn(head (whatsIn (BoatHouseDc (BoatDc (PeopleDc "joe"))))))) == 
         (head (whatsOn(BoatDc (PeopleDc "joe"))))
```

Comment: Yes they do seem redundant.  You may want to use a constraint synonym instead, e.g. `type HouseBoatsC v p = (BoatsC v p, HousesC v p, PeopleC p)`